# Finding inverse using quadratic formula

Tags: calculus, quadratic-forms, inverse-function

We must find the inverse of:$ h(t) = -5t^2+30t+60 $  ...
$0= -5t^2+30t+60-h $

We use quadratic formula. I am trying to understand how the denominator plays in to the solution presented:
$$t = \frac{−30 ± \sqrt{30^2+20(60 − h)}}{-10}
$$
$$= {3 ± \sqrt{3^2+.2(60 − h)}}  $$ ... and so on.

I see that we divide out the denominator from $ -b $ in the quadratic formula, I dont understand why $3^2$ remains positive having been divided by a negative ($-10$), and how we get $0.2$ from dividing $20$ in the numberator by $-10$.

Also, why would the same reduction not apply to the coefficient $60$ in $(60-h)$ ?

any insight is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: $$t=\frac{-30\pm \sqrt{30^2+20(60-h)}}{-10}$$.Multiplying numerator and denominator by $-1$,$$t=\frac{30\mp \sqrt{30^2+20(60-h)}}{10}$$ $$3\mp \frac{\sqrt{30^2+20(60-h)}}{10}$$ $$3+\sqrt{\frac{30^2}{10^2}+\frac{20}{10^2}(60-h)}$$

Answer (score 1):

The impact of dividing by a negative number is shown below.

\begin{align}t &= \frac{−30 \pm \sqrt{30^2+20(60 − h)}}{-10}\\
&= {3 \color{red}{\mp} \sqrt{\frac{30^2+20(60 − h)}{10^2}}}   \end{align}

For example $\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{-1}=-1-\sqrt{2}$ and $\frac{1-\sqrt{2}}{-1}=-1+\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Thank you @Siong Thye Goh ! I do not understand why we square10 in the denominator on the second line. Is there a general rule of thumb when divinding into a radical?

Comment: as you pull a positive number out of the square root, it receive a square root. as you bring in a positive number inside the square root, the oppositive happens, it gets squared. $2\sqrt{1}= \sqrt{2^2}$